# approximating a page tab on a profile?

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

Currently, only **pages** and not **profiles** support **tabs**. Any suggestions on how I might "approximate" the appearance and functionality of a tab on a profile (instead of a page)?

Answer (score 1):

You really can't, especially now with Timeline. Its just a stream of information.